# Why are neither my "if" nor "else" statements being executed?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

In each statement I define what the var "highScores" is, but the program seems to skip ahead and tell me that it is nil before it even runs either statement.  I would think at the very least, my print statements would execute before continuing on.

```
    func retrieveScores() {

    var highScores: [Int]?

    if var prevHighScores = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "highScores") as? [Int] {

        print("there were previous high scores")

        if displayedScore > prevHighScores.last! {

            prevHighScores.insert(displayedScore, at: 0)
            highScores = prevHighScores.sorted()
        }

    } else {

        print("there were NOT previous high scores")

        highScores = Array(repeating: Int(0), count: 10)
        highScores![0] = displayedScore
        UserDefaults.standard.set(highScores, forKey: "highScores")
    }

    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS  //
    for index in 0...highScores!.count - 1 {

        let thisLabel = SKLabelNode(text: String(describing: highScores![index]))
        thisLabel.color = UIColor.orange
        thisLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: (view!.bounds.height * 0.75) -
            CGFloat((index+1) * 25))
        thisLabel.fontName = "Cochin"
        thisLabel.fontSize = 20

        addChild(thisLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting break points inside either {} to see if they are even attempted to be executed?  My initial thought is that that first `if` condition is satisfied, and then the `if` condition nested within it is not, which would cause the program to move on to the for loop.

Comment: But you're right, if that were the case, the print should still occur

Comment: you should initialize your highScores with an empty `[ ]`array instead of making it optional and loop through it using its indices `for index in highScores.indices {`

Comment: I'm having trouble believing that neither of the print statements would execute.  Do you have an example project that you can share?

Comment: @LeoDabus Just doing your first suggestion worked, thank you!  I moved the "var highScores = Array(repeating: Int(0), count: 10)" bit to the beginning of the function.  Would someone explain why that works but my original didn't?

Comment: @Pierce yes I tried that, and it still skipped them.

Answer (score 0):

```
if var prevHighScores = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "highScores") as? [Int] {
```

should read

```
if let prevHighScores = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "highScores") as? [Int] {
```

I'm gunna clean it up a bit though because I'm bored..
I make use of the nil coalescing operator here. So if it doesn't grab highscores from the UserDefaults, it returns the array of ten 0's

```
func retrieveScores() {

    var highScores = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "highScores") as? [Int] ?? [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10)

    if displayedScore > highScores.min() ?? 0 {
        highScores = (highScores + [displayedScore]).sorted(by: >)
        highScores.removeLast()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(highScores, forKey: "highScores") 
    }


    for (index, score) in highScores.enumerated() {

        let thisLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "\(score)")
        thisLabel.color = UIColor.orange
        thisLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: (view!.bounds.height * 0.75) -
            CGFloat((index+1) * 25))
        thisLabel.fontName = "Cochin"
        thisLabel.fontSize = 20

        addChild(thisLabel)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you enter the `if` branch (`prevHighScores` is set) and then `displayedScore <= prevHighScores.last!`, `highScores` is never set.

---

You have made your code unnecessarily unsafe by declaring `highScores` as an optional and later force-unwrapping it. You should use this structure instead:

```
func retrieveScores(a: Int, b: Int) {

    var highScores: [Int]

    if a > 0 {
        if b > 0 {
            highScores = [1,1,1]
        }
    } else {
        highScores = [0,0,0]
    }

    for score in highScores {
        print(score)
    }
}
```

Now the compiler detects that there is a path through your conditionals that does not instantiate `highScores` so it correctly complains that it may be not be set at the position you indicate.

Keep in mind that the compiler does not *execute* anything; it performs *static*, that is *compile-time*, analysis of your code. Even if that failing path never happens and you know it, the *compiler* has no way to telling!

---

If you need to have `highScores` be an optional, you can still make your code safe like so:

```
var highScores: [Int]?

...

if let scores = highScores {
    for score in scores {
        print(score)
    }
} else {
    print("No scores found!")
}
```

General advice: Make the compiler work for you! You have static typing and type checking at your disposal; use them to avoid as many runtime errors as possible!

Comment: If I loop through using `highScores.indices` instead of `highscores.count` I for some reason don't get the error anymore.  The problem now is that UserDefaults gets rewritten each time.  

In your version of the retrieveScores function, it looks like you would already need to read from UserDefaults.  Would you do that in the same way that I did above?

Comment: @LukeMorse I focused on the core issue here. What else is going on with your data flows, I don't know.